# How to share table property between two tables in ADO Entity Data?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, relational-database, entity-relationship

i'm having a little problem in my project. i'm using ADO.Net Entity Data Model,
let's say i have 2 Tables:

1. Offices : a. id
            b. Name
2. Requests: a. rid
            b.fname
            c.lname
            d.mobile

i want the requests table will have a relations to the offices table that each row in requests will have the id of the one of the tables.
i tried to do 1 to many relations but it didn't work , i just couldnt add data to the table.

thanks for your guidence

Answer (score 0):

Your Requests table needs to have a field to relate back to the offices table.  Which typically should be named OfficeID or something similar.  Add that field and create the relationship from Offices.ID to Requests.OfficeID and it will work fine.